# MS Outlook Cannot Drag & Drop Files

Tags: microsoft-outlook

This isn't a programming question, but I wasn't sure of a better place within stackexchange to put it:

Sometimes MS Outlook will freeze when using the app, such that you cannot drag & drop messages to folders (and maybe some other things freeze up, too).  There is a simple fix for this:

**just keep pressing ESC a few times**

This wakes MS Outlook back up.  Not sure what is really going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Do you have your PST file on a network drive?

Comment: @snowdude, no, I don't have it on a network drive in this case.  But if you follow the link, it appears this isn't related to drive access or anything like that.  If I were to guess, it's maybe an issue with memory (or perhaps virtual memory... in my case my virtual memory is on my desktop, not a network).

Answer (score 2):

**Just keep pressing ESC a few times**, this will wake MS Outlook back up.  [Here](http://it.thelibrarie.com/weblog/2010/06/drag-and-drop-stops-working/) is a link that goes into a bit more detail.

I just wanted to make sure this tip was placed somewhere within StackExchange for easier discovery.